# Cannot start service from the command line or debugger

Tags: c#, windows, service

I've created a windows service and installed it on a server. It appears to work fine ie doing what its meant to do. But when I log on to the server through remote desktop I get this message:

> Cannot start service from the command line or debugger. A windows
>   Service must first be installed(using installutil.exe) and then
>   started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Administrative tool
>   or the NET START command.

I click on and then go to the services explorer to check the service, its started ok. No errors reported.

I've installed this so it uses Local System as "Log On As".

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that exactly that service throw error message?

Comment: The message only started to appear once I installed my windows and the service reads XML files and needs to run continuously. I will look at this after Christmas as that's when I'm back in work. Just seems strange that it occurs since I installed my service. But like I said it works but just don't want this message appearing when users login via remote desktop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Service start failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157176/windows-service-start-failure)

Answer (score 43):

Change the `Main` method in `Program` class as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    private static void Main()
    {
        var myService = new MyService();
        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting service...");
            myService.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Service is running.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            Console.WriteLine("Stopping service...");
            myService.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Service stopped.");
        }
        else
        {
            var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { myService };
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
        }
    }
```

You have to add a `Start` method to your service class:

```
    public void Start()
    {
        OnStart(new string[0]);
    }
```

Change the output type of the project to 'Console Application' instead of 'Windows Application' in the 'Application' tab of the project properties. Now you can just press F5 to start debugging but you can still run the executable as a Windows Service.

Comment: @Tadej did you rebuild?

Comment: @MattCom i found another way to do it. But can't remember exactly what is was.

Answer (score -4):

Press CTRL-ALT-CANC (*), and go to Services tab. There is a list of services, search the one you need to start, select it and click "start".
If it's not there, maybe it was uninstalled, not (correctly?) installed, or for some other reason your service is not known by Windows.

(*) or CTRL-ALT-DEL(ete) or others, depending by the keyboard language.

Comment: CANC? Is that Delete?

Comment: Thanks, i added a (*) with clarification.I didn't think that this depends by the keyboard.

Answer (score -4):

Goto App.config

Find

```
<setting name="RunAsWindowsService" serializeAs="String">
<value>True</value>
```

Set to False