# Can not run service on Windows

Tags: c#, service

When I start "F5" in a project in Visual Studio 2015, the program show me the message:

> Can not you start the service from the command line or in the
>   debugger. The windows service must be installed 's First (using
>   installutil.exe ) and then started with ServerExplorer , the
>   administrative tool for Windows Services or the NET START command"

How can I resolve these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a Windows Service as a console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157176/run-a-windows-service-as-a-console-app)

Comment: Have you even tried to use Google? It's faster than posting a question and gives you faster results. Or at the very least read the error message

Comment: There is a lot of documentation on this out there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach is to do it the way Windows Services were traditionally debugged.

1. Install the service (I set up a External Tool entry in VS to do this)
2. Run the service via the SCM
3. Attach the debugger (VS) to the running process - perform your debugging session
4. Stop and uninstall the service (I have a External Tool entry in VS for this as well)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Service in C# i not that easy you can follow this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) it is a complete Walkthrough on how to create a C# service and how to run/debug it.

I don't like to do this so most of the time i will just use a ConsoleApplication an hide it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application).