# Visual Studio project builds into dll rather than executable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, console-application

I'd imagine this as a massively dumb question but when I build my solution (console app) it creates a dll rather than an executable. Am I doing something wrong or just misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: Is it a .NET Core project?

Comment: I think it is (I'm pretty new to VS)

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705465/build-net-core-as-an-exe-not-a-dll) out. I'm sort of hesitant to flag it as a direct duplicate, but at the very least it's related.

Comment: Don't guess, look at the application type in the property page of your project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Please, show a console app project properties, or property group from `cspoj` file

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on your project in Solution Explorer and select `Properties` in the bottom of Context Menu. Select proper `Output type` then as marked on the screendhot.

[image]

As mentioned in another answer here: in case your Target framework is `.NET Core`, use `Publish` in the `Build` menu of Visual Studio width setting `Target runtime` format, for example `win-x86` to make a proper output application format.

Check out the reference: [Publish your .NET Core application with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio)

Comment: This assumes that OP's project is framework rather than core. You might want to at least mention that this is a fix for framework.

Comment: It would probably be a little more helpful to say something like "Right-click on your project in Solution Explorer" instead of saying "ConsoleApp1". That might not be the name of OP's project. Also, typo on "screenshot".

Comment: Thanks for comments. Added `.NET Core` note and fixed "on your project"

Answer (score 1):

If this is .Net Framework then more than likely the project output type is set to Class Library in the project properties page.

To fix this you must ensure that you have a method with a signature of `static void Main()` and set the Output type to Console Application.

To Change the Output Type:

1. Right click the Project name in the Solution Explorer
2. Select Properties
3. On the Application tab change Output Type to Console Application
4. Change the Startup object drop down to the class that contains your
   Main method.
5. Save the Properties and try to build/debug again.

Comment: Exact same result after doing this :/

Comment: @smeel - verify whether your project is framework or core. If it's core then this isn't going to address your issue.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's legit.  At least for .NET Core 2.x.  For .NET Core 3.x, it does build an .EXE.  You could always run it by running: `dotnet foo.dll`.

So for now, instead of Build, use Publish.  That will generate an .EXE.

I typically keep a command handy to just generate it quickly:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64 --self-contained:false
```

Comment: How would I use that command to export it? Where do I input it?

Comment: @smeel Open Command Prompt in the same directory as your .csproj file.  Then just run this.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Publishing to exe from Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio)

*Right Click Project > Publish > Configure*

- Select `Deployment Mode: Self-Contained`
- Select `Preferred Target Runtime`
- Note down the *Target location*
- Hit Publish

*You will now find your exe in the target location that you made note of*

Note: The default option is set to Framework dependant mode, which is why you see the *dll* file as the output and to run that you can `dotnet MyConsoleApp.dll`

#### .NetCore 2.1 / 2.2 / 3.0  (Via Command Line)

- [Publish SelfContained App:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli)

  `dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64 --self-contained true`

#### .NetCore  3.0  (Via Command Line)

- [Publish SelfContained SingleFile App:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables)

  `dotnet publish -r win10-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true`
- [Publish Trimmed Self Contained App:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#assembly-linking)

  *.CSProj*

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
  <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```

  `dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64 --self-contained true`